# Send Email in Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

This is code am using for sending email with attachment ( sample.txt -- test file ),

but am not receiving any mail's and no error's were thrown

i tried to send a mail without the attachment and, it WORKED...

What am i doing wrong for attachment part ?

```
def sendmail():
    try:
        #...
        msg.body = "Hello Flask message sent from Flask-Mail"
        with app.open_resource("sample.txt") as fp:
            msg.attach("sample.txt", "text/plain", fp.read())
        mail.send(msg)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
return "Check Your Inbox !!!"
```

Comment: I think that your code looks fine.  Try removing "text/plain", like this: `msg.attach("sample.txt", fp.read())` or try full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This code below works for me.  I use gmail's SMTP server in the example.
Run this program first

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_mail import Message

# Configure these
sender = 'fred@example.com'
recip = 'fred@example.com'
image = 'example.png'
mailpass = 'aabbcc'

app = Flask(__name__)
mail = Mail(app)

app.extensions['mail'].server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.extensions['mail'].port = 587
app.extensions['mail'].use_tls = True
app.extensions['mail'].username = sender
app.extensions['mail'].password = mailpass


@app.route('/')
def sendmail():
    msg = Message('This is a test email',
                  sender=sender,
                  recipients=[recip])

    with app.open_resource(image) as f:
        msg.attach('image.png', 'image/png', f.read())
    mail.send(msg)
    return 'mail sent'
app.run('localhost', 8888)
```

Then trigger the REST call:

```
curl localhost:8888/
```

I don't run the program from flask only because I am debugging it in PyCharm. By doing all the above the picture appears in my gmail view.